# how to auto submit in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I use zend framework 2 to develop website and i want to use auto submit in zend form. In form, i have submit button with id is "submitbutton". How to make auto submit with this form with javascript.

Comment: what do you mean auto submit? give more detail and some code you tried

Comment: thanks, you can see it in below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure javascript:

```
 document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

Jquery

```
 $("#myForm").submit();
```